# Closed embedding in flat topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $j:Y \to X$ be a closed embedding of schemes.

Then we know there is an exact sequence in the Zariski topology

$0 \to I \to \mathcal{O}_X \to j_{*} \mathcal{O}_Y \to 0$.

Now consider the sheaf $\mathbb{G}_a$ in the fppf topology.

Does there exist a similar exact sequence in the fppf topology?

$0 \to I \to \mathbb{G}_a  \to j_{*} \mathbb{G}_a \to 0$.

If yes, how do we describe the sheaf $I$ in this case? Is it quasicoherent?

Comment: Since all the sheaves are quasi-coherent, they automatically define sheaves in the fppf topology. Thus the description of $I$ in the zariski topology should be good enough to describe this sheaf in fppf topology.